# Asterisk Originate Caller ID Display

Tags: asterisk, pbx, asteriskami

**Situation 1**

---

We use this Originate command to dial out.

```
Action: Originate 
Channel: DAHDI/g11/(Destination number)
Context: queue-123
EXTEN: 123
Priority: 1 
Timeout: 30000 
Callerid: (Destination number)
Async: yes
```

It was success but we would like to set the dial-out number that the DAHDI trunk should use.

**Situation 2**

---

We use this Originate command to dial out.

```
Action: Originate 
Channel: DAHDI/g11/(Destination number)
Context: queue-123
EXTEN: 123
Priority: 1 
Timeout: 30000 
Callerid: (One dial-out number from our PRI trunk)
Async: yes
```

It was success too that the remote party can see the specified dial-out number. But our agent in the queue will also see this dial-out number instead of the original destination number

---

**What I am looking for**

1. We can choose the dial-out number from our PRI trunk (which has 100 numbers)
2. The remote party can see the dial-out number
3. Our agent can see the original destination number (remote party number) instead of the dial-out number

For now I can only choose whether Situation 1 or 2. We would like to archive both. Please help me to solve this Catch-22. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should change your cid before sending to queue  using something like

```
exten => _X.,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=${somevar})
```

Comment: Where should I put this? If I put this code, which situation should I use?

Answer (score 0):

`Callerid` should be the destination number and set the `CONNECTEDLINE` variable to the dialout number

```
Variable: CONNECTEDLINE(all,i)=Dial-out Name <dial-out number>
```